# Django, treat OneToOne related field as my own field

Tags: python, django, django-inheritance

I'm essentially trying to come up with my own inheritance scheme because Django's inheritance doesn't fit my needs.

I'd like parent table(class) hold common data fields.
sub classess would have its own additional data in a separate table.

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):

    common = models.IntegerField()

    def get_price(self):
        return some_price


class FooProduct(ProductBase):

    # no field because I'm proxy

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def get_price(self):
        return price_using_different_logic


class FooExtra(models.Model):

    base = models.OneToOneField(ProductBase, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

My question is, would it be able to treat as if Foo has `FooExtra`'s fields?

I'd like to do things like following..

```
foo = FooProduct.objects.create()

foo.phone = "3333"  # as django does with its multiple inheritance
foo.save()
FooProduct.objects.filter(phone="3333")
```

I'd like to list Products of different kind(data)

1. I need to list them together, so abstract Base inheritance is out
2. from the list, I'd like to treat each model as polymorphic model, when iterating over ProductBase.objects.all(), product.get_price() will use appropriate classe's method. (without incurring join if don't have to)
3. When and only when I want, I retrieve the addtional table data (by something like `.select_related('fooextra')`

[Django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) is close to what I want, but it is rather obscure what it does so I'm afraid to use it, and I think it fails #3.

Comment: What is it about Django's default model inheritance that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Ben: I've edited the question to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want inheritance and you want the fields that are specific to the child class to be on a separate table.
As far as I know, you don't need a proxy class to achieve that, you could just implement multi-table inheritance as specified in the manual at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance e.g.:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    common = models.IntegerField()


class Foo(Base):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This, as explained at the link above, will automatically create a one-to-one relationship. And of course you can do `foo.phone = "3333"` (where `foo` is of type `Foo`) as in your example above. And the neat thing is that you can also access `foo.common` whereas in your example it would have been `foo.base.common`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you want anything different to Django's standard inheritance.

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    common1 = models.IntegerField()
    common2 = models.IntegerField()

class FooProduct(ProductBase):
    fooextra = models.IntegerField()

class BarProduct(ProductBase):
    barextra = models.IntegerField()
```

If you create instances of each:

```
foo1 = FooProduct(common1=1, common2=1, fooextra=1)
foo2 = FooProduct(common1=1, common2=1, fooextra=2)
bar1 = BarProduct(common1=1, common2=1, barextra=1)
bar2 = BarProduct(common1=1, common2=1, barextra=2)
```

You can loop over all products:

```
for product in ProductBase.objects.all():
    print product.common1, product.common2
```

From a `ProductBase` object that is actually a `FooProduct`, you can get the custom field with:

```
product.foo.fooextra
```

From a `ProductBase` object that is actually a `BarProduct`, you can get the custom field with:

```
product.bar.barextra
```

You can still do querying:

```
foo = FooProduct.objects.get(fooextra=1)
bar = BarProduct.objects.get(barextra=2)
```

And you can access the common fields directly on those objects:

```
foo.common1
bar.common2
```

You can use the `InheritanceManager` from [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) if you need more control over querying etc - and this should address point 3, too: `ProductBase.objects.filter(...).select_subclasses()` would give you the `FooProduct` and `BarProduct` objects instead of `ProductBase` objects.

Comment: Nice answer, you beat me by 1 minute :-)

Comment: I think it fails #2, `polymorphic`, if base has `def price(self)` and foo has it's own version `ProductBase.objects.all():` won't use polymorphic price.

Comment: It will if you call select_subclasses from the model utils package

Comment: @ben: that incurs join and violates #3, I don't want to join for polymorphic behavior (unless I need to)

Comment: Are you certain that it doesn't do that when it needs to instead of initially? I haven't tested so I don't know. Also, unless you've tested this and the performance is too slow for you, I'm not sure what the reason behind that requirement is.

Comment: select_subclasses does join, Suppose you have 10 product types, you would need to join 10 times..

Comment: Then I guess you will have to find another way. This seems to get you 95% of the way without any extra work or third party libraries, and I'm not sure I understand the benefits of only doing the join when you need to.